# javascript json parse with single quote

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to transform into a json object the an object this works well with the following object and the associated code :

```
myStr = "{'key':'value'}"
JSON.parse(myStr.replace(/'/g, "\""));
```

The problem is that with the same code, I am getting an exception with the following object :

```
myStr = "{'key':'val'ue'}"
```

The error is unexpected token u. I would like to keep the single quote between l and u, and not replace it.

Is there anyway?

Comment: you need to escape \' that one. or encode.

Comment: Whatever system is generating `"{'key':'val'ue'}"` should be slapped. That's not valid.

Comment: I agree with @xdumaine.  If you're able to alter the original system, fix the problem at the source rather than trying to patch the mess

Comment: You can try to replace single quot to double only in occurances like `{'`, `':'`, `'}`, `','` . In all other cases replace quot with `\'`.

May be this can help in your case, but overall approach is definitely weird.

Comment: I need to keep the single quote, my example was probably bad. For example : the value can be kevin's dog. There I need to keep the single quote once I have parse the data for displaying it then

Comment: If you generate proper JSON, then you don't have any of these problems.

Comment: The example is clear, but you should really explain a) where that value is coming from and b) why it doesn't generate valid JSON.

Comment: As a minor note: json ought to use double-quotes; single quotes are valid for javascript objects, which are almost-but-not-quite json.

Comment: I generate manually the json in my cshtml view; i am developping an asp.net mvc app

Comment: Ok yeah that's you #1 problem. **Don't generate JSON manually.** Asp.net has a built-in way to generate valid JSON.

Comment: If you're manually generating it, generate it validly: `mystr = '{"key":"val\'ue"}'`

Comment: Could you show us how you're generating the JSON, as it seems that that is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, but it feels a little hacky...

```
JSON.parse(myStr.replace(/{'/g, "{\"").replace(/'}/g, "\"}").replace(/':'/g, "\":\""));
```

Comment: It... works. Although it's a workaround for a different problem

Comment: I agree, fixing problems at the source is infinitely better than using equally bad solutions to fix them.

Comment: This solution seems to work but it would be nice if you could explain a little bit, especially the last replace. I understand that the 2 first replace are for the extremes quotes.

Comment: The last replace is following the same idea of replacing the single quotes with the character(s) next to them. In this case it's the colon between the key and the value. You want the colon to be surrounded by double quotes, not single quotes, so that's what it does. The backslashes are just escape characters, in case you weren't aware.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this may help you. Assuming the inner singe quote comes between alphabets.

```
myStr = "{'key':'val'ue'}"
JSON.parse(myStr.replace(/([a-z])'([a-z])/g, "$1\\'$2"));
```